# MySQL query a set of data, need to merge deduplicate issues

Tags: mysql

Let's say that I have the following data:

| column_name |
| --- |
| a, b |
| b |
| c, d |

If you want to merge this column and deduplicate duplicate characters, how to write SQL?

Note: "a, b" is a string type, and you need to do "a, b", "b", "c, d". After merging, the result is "a, b, c, d".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) SEPARATOR ',') AS merged_column
FROM mytable 
JOIN (
    SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
) numbers ON numbers.n <= LENGTH(data) - LENGTH(REPLACE(data, ',', '')) + 1;

-- Change mytable with your table name
-- And data with your Column Name
```